# Regex word-boundary not working as expected

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, word-boundary

I'm trying replace `CT` with `COURT` regardless of where it appears in a string (using Snowflake SQL). I would expect this to work:

```
select
    regexp_replace('36 HERITAGE CT', '\bCT\b', 'COURT'),
    regexp_replace('36 HERITAGE CT #204', '\bCT\b', 'COURT')
```

But the output is always `36 HERITAGE CT` no matter what I do.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `\mCT\M` in the match.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#:~:text=Table%C2%A09.22.%C2%A0Regular%20Expression%20Constraint%20Escapes

Comment: @MikeOrganek sorry updated to specifically call out that I'm using Snowflake. I tried your solution and it does work in Postgres but not Snowflake :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per documentation, [`\b` is supported](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html#label-regexp-general-usage-notes).

Use

```sql
regexp_replace('36 HERITAGE CT', '\\bCT\\b', 'COURT')
```

See **Note**:

> In [single-quoted string constants](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text.html#label-single-quoted-string-constants), you must escape the backslash character in the backslash-sequence. For example, to specify `\d`, use `\\d`. For details, see [Specifying Regular Expressions in Single-Quoted String Constants](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html#label-regexp-escape-character-caveats) (in this topic).
>
> You do not need to escape backslashes if you are delimiting the [string with pairs of dollar signs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text.html#label-dollar-quoted-string-constants) (`$$`) (rather than single quotes).